# How to deny shell execution in all sub-directories?

Tags: nginx, security

I want nginx to deny users who have folders inside /webroot/uploads

e.g.

```
/webroot/uploads/user1
/webroot/uploads/user2
/webroot/uploads/user1000
```

to execute any shell (php, pl, exe).

The shells are often hidden in jpg or gif files. like badfile.php.jpg

I also see malacious binary files being uploaded to the folder.

Here my preliminary rules:

```
location ~ /webroot/uploads/(.+)\.php$ {
 deny all;
}

location ~ /webroot/uploads/(.+)\.pl$ {
 deny all;
}
```

But I am not sure it is robust. So I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to absolutely ensure nothing executes in /webroot/uploads, or anywhere underneath, I would suggest blocking execution at the filesystem level.  Create a filesystem for /webroot/uploads, and mount it with the 'noexec' option:

```bsh
mount -t ext4 -o 'noexec,rw' /dev/<device-name> /webroot/uploads/
```

*Note:* If you're using a managed server, or otherwise don't have available storage to provision for a filesystem, you can mount this on to a loopback device:

**Warning:** Before running the following commands, back up /webroot/uploads and move the files to a temporary location.

1. Return the next available loop device - will be one of /dev/loop[0-8]

   ```bsh
   sudo losetup -f
   ```
2. Create an image to act as the filesystem - this creates a 1GB file in /opt

   ```bsh
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/opt/uploads_fs.img bs=1M count=1024
   ```
3. Configure the loopback device returned in the first command to use the new file

   ```bsh
   losetup /dev/loop0 /opt/uploads_fs.img
   ```
4. Create a filesystem

   ```bsh
   mkfs.ext4 -m 1 -v /dev/loop0
   ```
5. Mount /webroot/uploads on the new device with noexec set

   ```bsh
   mount -t ext4 -o 'noexec,rw' /dev/loop0 /webroot/uploads/
   ```

**At this point**, restore your files to their previous locations.  Even as the root user, you will not be able to execute files on that filesystem:

```bsh
[root@localhost testfs]# ll myscript*   
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 41 Jan 21 19:20 myscript.sh  
[root@localhost testfs]# ./myscript.sh  
-bash: ./myscript.sh: Permission denied  
[root@localhost testfs]#
```

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting solution but I don't have a separate disk to assign to /webroot/uploads/

Comment: The second half of that solutions explains a workaround to that ... unless you mean you don't have appropriate access.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
location ~ /webroot/uploads/.*\.(php|pl|rb|sh)$ {
  deny all;
}
```

By default nginx doesn't pass files to a parser or execute them. It'll simply serve them. The deny rule is only necessary if you already have nginx configured to pass php/pl/rb files to something that will parse or execute them.

Comment: Well not sure what you mean. in my case nginx pass php requests to php-fpm. Als most files are not like badfile.php. your rules are basically abbreviation of mine but mine did not manage to avoid bad files execution.